# How to assign variable with autocomplete in the script

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I'm trying map variable in the script and give user ability point to right file using tab 
Here is the part of the code:

`read -p "Enter path to the file: " -i "" -e path VARIABLE`

I'm able to autocomplete with tab but when file is selected variable is not assigned 
Does anyone knows how to fix that?

Thanks 
Rafal

Comment: You use two variables names, and only `path` will be populated.

Comment: thanks  Benjamin W. for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write like this:

```
read -p "Enter path to the file: " -i "" -e VARIABLE
```

Then you can use TAB to select a file and the file pathname will be saved in the VARIABLE.

Comment: I don't think `-i ''` does anything. Empty is the default state of the prompt.